# Why are the results of StringMethods comparisons not automatically converted to boolean array?

Tags: python, pandas

I was testing my dataset and was trying to compare strings using pandas
StringMethods and discovered that I cannot compare boolean array generated 
by the StringMethods with another boolean array unless saving it to the variable

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"pet":"cat", "gender":"M"}, {"pet":"Cat", "gender":"M"}, {"pet":"dog", "gender":"F"}])

result = df[df.gender== "M" & df.pet.str.lower() == "cat"]
# TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

But when saving it to a variable before using binary operators it seems to work.

```
first = df.gender == "M"
second = df.pet.str.lower() == "cat"
df[(first) & (second)]

#   gender  pet
# 0      M  cat
# 1      M  Cat
```

Based on the error message, `df.pet.str.lower() == "cat"` isn't converted to a boolean array until I save them to the variable.
Why are the results of StringMethods  comparisons not automatically converted to boolean array?

Comment: Mind the order of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"pet":"cat", "gender":"M"}, {"pet":"Cat", "gender":"M"}, {"pet":"dog", "gender":"F"}])

result = df[ (df.gender== "M") & (df.pet.str.lower() == "cat")]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an order of operations problem. `&` is binding more tightly than `==`, so when you put them on the same line, the logic is changed. Add parens around the `==` clauses and it should work.